# Вывод элемента list типа класса

Tags: c#

Список pbook имеет тип Person и хранит список абонентов. Я вывожу с помощью метода Show класса Phonebook, но мне выводит ссылку Phonebook.Person. Как правильно вывести список абонентов в телефонном справочнике?

**Класс Phonebook:**

```
class Phonebook
{  
    private List<Person> pbook = new List<Person>();

    public Phonebook()
    {
    }

    public void addPerson(Person p)
    {
        pbook.Add(p);
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        foreach (var person in pbook)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(person);
        }
    }

    public void Menu()
    {
        int control = 0;
        while (control != 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Сделайте выбор: 1 - добавить абонента, 2 - вывести абонента, 3 - выход.");
            control = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (control)
            {
                case 1:
                    Person p = new Person();
                    Console.WriteLine("Введите фио:");
                    p.AddName(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Введите телефон:");
                    p.AddPhone(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Введите адрес:");
                    p.AddAddress(Console.ReadLine());
                    addPerson(p);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Show();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Класс Person:**

```
class Person
{
    private string Name;
    private string Phone;
    private string Address;

    public Person()
    {          
    }

    public void AddName(string n)
    {
        Name = n;
    }

    public void AddPhone(string p)
    {
        Phone = p;
    }

    public void AddAddress(string a)
    {
        Address = a;
    }

    public void ShowPerson()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ФИО: {0}, номер: {1}, адрес: {0}", Name, Phone, Address);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это ваш код?))) Вам надо переопределить в классе Person метод toString() или по вашему коду надо использовать

```
public void Show()
{
    foreach (var person in pbook)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(person.ShowPerson());
    }
}
```

Comment: Мой код. А что не так в моем коде, что у тебя появляются сомнения, в том, что это не мой код? Я пишу для себя этот телефонный справочник, как везде советуют выбрал учебный проект для закрепления теории, который будет интересен.

Comment: да мне как-то всеравно, видно, чо код учебный, но вопрос твой твой показался странным изза того, что весь принцип ООП тебе не понятен пока

Comment: что именно мне не понятно по вашему мнению?

Comment: Конкретно в Вашем коде бросается в глаза, то что Вам не понятно что именно означает переменная person в строках кода foreach (var person in pbook) { Console.WriteLine(person); }. Каким типом она является, и что именно она должна содержать в себе. Советую вам во время обучения не использовать var, а использовать именно то, чем является этот тип, в данном случае Person. Тогда будет более понятно что должно отобразиться на экране. В данном случае отобразиться именно как тип, а не его содержимое - PhoneBook.Person (Person - это тип/класс, а PhoneBook - это не тип или класс, а пространство имен)

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка, бросающаяся в глаза - это зависимость метода ShowPerson от консоли. В Windows-приложении это работать не будет.

Как Вам порекомендовал krupennikov, лучше для этого переопределить метод ToString, чтобы он возвращал строку - а уже эту строку можно писать, например, в консоль. Вместо Show, вероятно, тоже было бы логично использовать ToString.

Ещё вызывает недоумение сочетание `while (control != 3)` и `Environment.Exit`. Что-то из этого явно лишнее, по идее, должно работать и без `Environment.Exit`. Если не работает, разбирайтесь в отладчике, где ошибка.

Answer (score -1):

Парень правильно написал. В классе Person добавляете

```
void override ToString()
{
    Console.WriteLine("ФИО: {0}, номер: {1}, адрес: {0}", this.Name, this.Phone, this.Address);
}
```

А в классе PhoneBook в выводе элемента списка просто пишете:

```
public void Show()
{
    foreach (var person in pbook)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(person.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: зачем добавлять? там уже все есть =) если ему удобней пользоваться своим методом ShowPerson(), пусть так и будет, просто надо понимать что есть еще и ToString() =)

Comment: `void override ToString()` - это нонсенс. Он не может возвращать `void`, только `string`. Ну и содержимое метода должно быть другим. Не `Console.WriteLine`, а `string.Format`.

Comment: почему лучше переопределить и использовать метод ToString()?

Comment: я не уверен, но мне кажется все знают, что у всех объектов языка, есть метод toString, потому нагружать код своим методом - лишнее, выше, кто-то написал про зависимость к консолям в разных ОС, но я в этом не уверен, так как говорится про исходный код( а не про екзешник) в котором есть синтаксис, который одинаковый для языка, во всех операционках